# jquery tabs css fluid layout

Tags: css, layout, jquery-ui-tabs, fluid

quick question. I have a tabbed interface for my site but I have all the parts of the site crashing into each other. How do I achieve a fluid layout where it simply resizes when the display is smaller. I read a few articles @ alistapart and made my containing div relative to the browser window and every other div within the d container relative and still nothing. any clues on what else I should be trying?

[alt text http://www.thelawyerschronicle.com/images/siteprob.jpg](http://www.thelawyerschronicle.com/images/siteprob.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or code?

Comment: do you want the css code or the html? I can add the screenshot.

Comment: here is the screenshot, I don't know what I should be doing?

Comment: Posting your CSS for the banner will help us figure out the problem with that. See my answer below re the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The two biggest problems I see are the banner ad on top of everything else, and the tabs running over to the next line.

The tabs seem to do that simply because you have too many. You'll either need to make them smaller/decrease padding, etc. or put fewer items in the menu.

It looks like the banner isn't positioned correctly. Margin/padding?

Comment: I tried the padding and margins a bit more but still. I am going to keep pluggin away and post my answers.